# Swift / How to avoid, that UITableView rowHeight changes unwanted

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a UITableViewController with dynamic cells and different sections. Once the controller is getting called, the rowHeigths are perfect. Then I'm moving to another controller (within another rootViewController) - completely off context and strings of the UITableViewController.

Once I go back to the UITableViewController, viewDidLoad will not be called anymore. That is fine.
But all the cells are having the same size (I'd say 44, what is the basic row height).

Is there any possibility to avoid this behavior?

This is my code and it is the only time the rowHeight is set:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   if indexPath.section == 0 {
       tableView.rowHeight = 125

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("bla") as! bla
       return cell
   }

   if indexPath.section == 1 {
       tableView.rowHeight = 80

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("bla") as! bla
       return cell
   }

   if indexPath.section == 2 {
       tableView.rowHeight = 50

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("bla") as! bla
       return cell

   }

   if indexPath.section == 3 {
       tableView.rowHeight = 60

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("bla") as! bla
       return cell
   }

   if indexPath.section == 4 {
       tableView.rowHeight = 450

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("bla") as! bla
       return cell

   }

   return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method for setting different cell height in same tableview.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    var cellHeight : CGFloat = 44.0
    switch indexPath.section
    {
        case 0: cellHeight  = 125.0
        case 1: cellHeight  = 80.0
        case 2: cellHeight  = 50.0
        case 3: cellHeight  = 60.0
        case 4: cellHeight  = 450.0
        default: cellHeight = 44.0 
    }
    return cellHeight
}
```

Please refer  [UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:) for more details about this delegate method.

Comment: awesome. it's working. only edit needed is "!" not need at tableviewcontroller

Comment: i gues i can delete the rowHeight declaration at the cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: You don't need that rowHeight declaration in cell for row at indexpath